# Calling Attributes from Class inside of a Class Method, Code Error

Tags: python, class, instance

I'm new to classes in any programming language, however currently I am trying to create a program that will calculate a users tax position based on inputs.

The issue I'm having is that when I call the attributes in method def get_threshold the figures are not adding up.  I have declared the input as **int** but it appears to be generating a list when I run the method and the numbers don't add up.

Is anybody able to kindly explain what I have done wrong?

The idea will be that the class will hold all of the user's income and pension contribution details, calculate the tax position and the program will be able to print relevant tax information.

I have written the code without using classes however would like to move it into a class so that I can request information for additional clients if it's required.

```
class Client:

    def __init__(self, name, salary, bonus, intdiv, pensionpercent, pensionlump):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.intdiv = intdiv
        self.pensionpercent = pensionpercent / 100
        self.pensionlump = pensionlump

    @classmethod
    def from_input(cls):
        return cls(input('name'), int(input('salary')), int(input('bonus')), int(input('enter interest and divdends for the year')),
                   int(input('enter workplace pension contributions as a %')), int(input('enter total of any lump sum contributions'))
                   )

    def get_threshold(self):

        totalgross = (self.salary + self.bonus + self.intdiv, self.pensionlump)
        print(totalgross)


c = Client.from_input()

c.get_threshold()
```

```
Code Returns:
name50000
salary5
bonus5
enter interest and divdends for the year5
enter workplace pension contributions as a %5
enter total of any lump sum contributions0
(15, 0)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a tuple in your method with the comma

```
def get_threshold(self):

    totalgross = (self.salary + self.bonus + self.intdiv, self.pensionlump) <-- comma is the cause
    print(totalgross)
```

If you want a single value you need to remove the comma, use a + instead. Or whatever your formula calls for.